# Oracle 10g Full text search

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

Oracle full text search not searching **How are you?**. Other search terms like Hi, Hello is searching

SQL code is:

```
SELECT input FROM input WHERE contains(input,'{"How are you?"}',10)>0
```

Comment: What is the data type of "input"?

Comment: varchar2 is the datatype for input